# Docker container killed with exit code 137 continued to increasingly consume disk space

Tags: docker, containers

one of my docker containers was killed with Exit code 137. So I ran another container of same image and did not prune the older, stopped container. However, it was increasingly consuming disk space as observed in overlay2 directory until docker ran out of disk space. Removing the stopped container solved the issue. What can the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

Each started container occupies some disk space (stored layers and logs).

You can inspect the disk spaced used per container with the following command:

`docker ps -s`

**EDIT**: if you run the same image more then once, the disk space is used also once, but for every change/build one or more layers are created and stored on the disk

Comment: yes, but the container that was killed with code 137 was increasingly consuming space, not any running one.

Comment: Was the container created with restart policy always?